# Not getting option for "Enable server based SharePoint integration" in Dynamics 365 to integrate Dynamics 365 with SharePoint online

Tags: dynamics-crm, integration, sharepoint-online

I am using trail account for integrate Dynamics 365 with SharePoint online.
But I am stuck at the step where I need to Enable server based SharePoint integration in Dynamics 365.

I am not getting option for "Enable server based SharePoint Integration".
Any help would be appreciated. Here I have attached screenshot for it.

[image]

**Updated**:

If enable server-based SharePoint integration is already enable, than why I am not getting option for "Document" at the below screenshot, where I can upload documents in Dynamics 365?

[image]

Comment: Have you followed all the steps to configure promptly?

Answer (score 0):

*Enable server-based SharePoint integration* is not available because it is already enabled.

You can directly go to *Document Management* to configure the entities you want to have enabled for SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for reply,   can you please help me little more, i am new to Dynamics 365 ::: how and where can i upload document in Dynamics 365?